# Button for setting MediaPlayer's volume to it's maximum sound as mute button set the volume to minimum?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am using this code to set volume to the minimum state (mute) but idk how to make it for maximum sound.

```
final ImageView mute = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mute);
  mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     int stateMin = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {
     stateMin = (stateMin+1)%2;
     player.setVolume(0,stateMin);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

volume is a double value in range of 0-1. 0 min , 1 max.